# VBA email lido Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

Possuo um VBA que salva todos os emails que chegam (os anexos) e gostaria de fazer com que o mesmo vba marcasse como lido. Como fazer? Segue meu código:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)

     Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    
    Dim sSaveFolder As String

        sSaveFolder = "Caminho da pasta de salvamento" 'onde salvar

For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments

oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy_hh-mm") & " - " & Attachment.DisplayName

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Para marcar o e-mail como lido, basta adicionar a linha `MItem.UnRead = False` antes do final do código. Isso fará com que o e-mail seja marcado como lido após salvar os anexos. Veja como ficaria o código atualizado:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String

sSaveFolder = "Caminho da pasta de salvamento" 'onde salvar

For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy_hh-mm") & " - " & Attachment.DisplayName
Next

MItem.UnRead = False 'marca o e-mail como lido

End Sub
```

Comment: Funcionou bem! Obrigado. Deu certo aqui